# Would it be overhead to use SpringMVC for rest only web project?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

I have to create java project that used only for rest webservices. I have to choose between **SpringMVC** and **Jersey**. I consider springMVC because we use SpringMVC in all our other projects. I considered Jersey because its standard(JAX-RS) and its created specially for Rest.

**Would it be overhead to use SpringMVC for rest only web project?** Or should I use Jersey(or any other JAX-RS implementation)

Comment: Most likely it's completely irrelevant whichever solution you choose.

Comment: This is typically more of a Java EE vs Spring debate - see here http://www.sivalabs.in/2015/06/a-developers-perspective-on-spring-vs.html

Comment: thanks, it gives food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also know how to configure / develop the backend in *both worlds* (CDI, Spring) it is really up to you.
But if you are more experienced with Spring(MVC) I would suggest that you use it or take a look at [spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) ([samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples) especially [spring-boot-hateoas](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-hateoas)).

Comment: Wouldn't springMVC be overhead with many extra functionalities? Or doesn't it worth considerations?

Comment: I don't think that it should bother you. Of course it is capable of more than you need. I really think you should not only look at the web layer but on your services / persistence layers and ask yourself how experienced are you in CDI or Spring. If you choose spring for your layers below web than you should stick with SpringMVC. On the other side: why not learn CDI ;)

Comment: I use spring at bussiness layer and I think i get my answer ). I don't know about CDI, but I should. ). Thanks for answer.